# Забрать текст между <BR> регулярка php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, dom

Например, есть произвольные данные вида:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
тедди  464 864<br>
цвет    464 864 оранж<br>
крепич строительный<br>
состав — 100% глина<br>
вес — 1000г<br>
длина — 250 м<br>
производство — италия<br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Нужно получить **отдельно данные по составу, весу и длине**. 
Порядок вывода данных - произвольный, т.е. на разных страницах строки могут стоять друг за другом в хаотичном порядке.

Думаю, нужно разбить на массив по 
 и получить отдельно элементы массива со словом "состав", "вес" и "длина".

Пытался так:

```
$vivod = "<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    тедди  464 864<br>
    цвет    464 864 оранж<br>
    крепич строительный<br>
    состав — 100% глина<br>
    вес — 1000г<br>
    длина — 250 м<br>
    производство — италия<br>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>";
$result = explode("<br>", $vivod);

print_r($result);
```

Но как получить элемент массива, внутри которого слово "состав", не могу понять. Нужна регулярка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего решением будет этот вариант:

```
$str = '<table>
<tr>
<td>
тедди  464 864<br>
цвет    464 864 оранж<br>
крепич строительный<br>
состав — 100% глина<br>
вес — 1000г<br>
длина — 250 м<br>
производство — италия<br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>';

$patt = '~(?:состав|вес|длина)\h—\h\K.+?(?=<br>)~';
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);
list($composition, $weight, $length) = $arr[0];
```

> *Но не могу понять, почему не выводит echo $arr[0]; ? Как забрать каждое из значений?*

Потому, что preg_match_all() возвращает двумерный массив, и для обращения к например составу нужно указывать два индекса `echo $arr[0][0];`. Или для удобства использовать, как в моём примере, конструкцию `list()` и обращение к переменным:

```
echo $composition; // состав
echo $weight; // вес
echo $length; // длина
```

---

**UPD**:

> *А возможно ли сделать выражение более универсальным, что бы оно находило строку, даже если ключевое слово находится за значением? пример: "250 м длина"*

Если позиции искомых символов заранее неизвестны, тогда можно сперва искать вхождение ключевого слова в строку, и если строка найдена - передавать её на обработку следующему шаблону, а соответствия сохранять в одномерный массив, и можно обращаться к его элементам по индексу (например, `echo[0];`). Ниже ваш html-код с прямой и обратной последовательностью искомых символов:

```
$str = '<table>
<tr>
<td>
тедди  464 864<br>
цвет    464 864 оранж<br>
крепич строительный<br>
состав — 100% глина<br>
вес — 1000г<br>
длина — 250 м<br>
250 м длина<br>
производство — италия<br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>';

$arr = [];
preg_replace_callback(
    '~^.*?(?:состав|вес|длина).+~m',
    function($m)use(&$arr){
        preg_match('~\d+\S?\h?\w+~u', $m[0], $tmp);
        $arr[] = $tmp[0];
    },
    $str
);

var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '100% глина' (length=15)
  1 => string '1000г' (length=6)
  2 => string '250 м' (length=6)
  3 => string '250 м' (length=6)
```

Comment: Кажется, подходит, спасибо! Но не могу понять, почему не выводит echo $arr[0]; ? Как забрать каждое из значений?

Comment: @Amsterdam я дописал пояснения в ответ.

Comment: спасибо, очень интересно и эффективно! А возможно ли сделать выражение более универсальным, что бы оно находило строку, даже если ключевое слово находится за значением? пример: "250 м длина"

Comment: @Amsterdam теоретически возможно. А на практике нужно чётко представлять, какие комбинации слов должны подпадать под соответствие.

Comment: @Amsterdam, мой вариант решает задачу - и с последовательностью у него нет проблем

Comment: @Jigius вы не верно поняли о последовательности, речь [вот о чём](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/070761017b482007695ed6edf343de8f3c5f36d5).

Comment: @Эдуард, поправил у себя, спс. Теперь отрабатывает и неполные данные. Но это ведь вопрос не последовательности, а неполных данных?

Comment: @Jigius это вопрос и последовательности, и _(скорее всего)_ неполных данных.

Comment: @Amsterdam я дописал пояснения в ответ.

Comment: @Эдуард Спасибо, шикарно!

Comment: @Эдуард а как сделать не чувствительным к регистру? Что бы понимал "длина" и "Длина". Не могу разобраться, куда поставить флажок "i" )

Comment: @Amsterdam модификатор i можно писать перед или после модификатора m. Т.е., после последнего символа-ограничителя.

Comment: @Эдуард интересно..так я и делал, однако, не срабатывает..Выдает ошибку если данные содержат заглавную букву: Notice:  Undefined offset

Comment: И еще увидел недочет в своем вопросе, который на реальном примере попадается: слово может быть завернуто в тег. Например: "<b>Состав</b> 100% глина<br>", и тогда код уже не срабатывает, выдает ошибку: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca08aafb181b3fd6ed23546593349d4afac8895a

Comment: @Amsterdam дак используйте код, который я дописал чуть позже.

Comment: Небольшое резюме: в итоге как не старались, код показывает себя как нежизнеспособный и совсем не универсальный... http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5580ec3c38697d831baac501f29bed2d58cdb7b8

Comment: @Amsterdam универсальных шаблонов не существует.

Comment: @Эдуард а не подскажите, почему не работает пример по ссылке? Дело в том, что эта регулярка используется в парсере для сайта-донора, где данные выводятся так неорганизованно, что где то "длина 10 м", где то "Длина: 10 м", где то "10 метров". Опора только тег <br>, который идет до и после фразы, и ключевые слова "длина/вес" или "метров/грамм", а так же "число+м", т.е. "10 г", "200 м". Очень непростая задача, плохо понимая регуглярки, потратил много времени, но справится не получается...

Comment: делаю такой вывод, но тоже какая то вакханалия получается. Вроде находит, но цепляется не за все число, а только за первую цифру, почему не ясно: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b35fff19b165dc6d28aacabf7c3af34ff59fbcc

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `preg_match_all()` и шаблона регулярного выражения, выделяем группы символов, содержащих названия параметров и их значений, для всех строк, которые начинаются со `слов состав/вес/длина`.

Далее, из полученного результата, формируем ассоциативный массив `$output`: ключи - найденные параметры, значения - найденные значения параметров.

```
<?php
$input = '
<table>
<tr>
<td>
тедди  464 864<br>
цвет    464 864 оранж<br>
крепич строительный<br>
состав — 100% глина<br>
вес — 1000г<br>
длина — 250 м<br>
производство — италия<br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>';

$output = array();
if (preg_match_all('/^(состав|вес|длина)\s+—\s+([^<]+)</mui', $input, $m)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($m[0]); $i++) {
        $output[$m[1][$i]] = $m[2][$i];
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

Результат:

```
array(3) {
  'состав' =>
  string(15) "100% глина"
  'вес' =>
  string(6) "1000г"
  'длина' =>
  string(6) "250 м"
}
```

Comment: спасибо за вариант реализации! Технику приму на вооружение безусловно. Регулярки недавно начал изучать, поэтому очень интересны различные способы

Comment: @Amsterdam, я исправил ошибку в коде. Теперь также работает с неполными данными